# How can I fix extremely slow falling movement on player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gravity

I found an extremely simple movement script, that works in Unity 3D. The only problem is that the player falls extremely slow (almost not). How can I fix this? It's like it's being slowed down by something, because other objects are falling at normal speed. changing project settings doesn't work either.

C# Code (assigned to player):

```
 public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
 {
     Rigidbody rb;
     public float speed;
  
     void Start()
     {
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
         Cursor.visible = false;
     }
 
     void Update()
     {
         rb.velocity = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
         transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are setting the velocity manually, and that overrides the physics engine (gravity) from also setting the velocity. You could fix it by only setting the X velocity by player action, and keep the Y velocity that is generated by gravity.

```
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction * speed, rb.velocity.y);
```

For jumping, you can apply a vertical force, so the gravity force will also still work

```
rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 5), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```